# How to plot a graph in R from mysql query data?

Tags: mysql, r

I have a R code in which I'm reading data from MySQL database.

```
conn <- dbConnect(
    drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),
    dbname = "shinytest",
    host = "localhost",
    username = "root",
    password = "root")

rs <- dbGetQuery(conn, "Select * from test;") 

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(box(

tableOutput('table')
)))


server <- function(input, output) {
output$table <- renderTable(rs)

}

dbDisconnect(conn)
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Now I want to create a chart for the data that was retrieved from the query in `rs`. How should I do this. I tried using the `plot` function but was unable to plot the chart with it.

Comment: Could you share your code for `plot`.

Comment: how specifically did you try to use `plot`?

Comment: @MichaelChirico I simply used `plot(rs$color, rs$quantity)`

Comment: And what was the result?

Comment: @MichaelChirico It doesn't work.Nothing shows up. Gives an error `Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: 
Warning messages:
1: 
In data.matrix(x) :
 NAs introduced by coercion
2: 
In data.matrix(x) :
 NAs introduced by coercion
3: 
In data.matrix(x) :
 NAs introduced by coercion
4: 
In data.matrix(x) :
 NAs introduced by coercion
5: 
In min(x) :
 no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf`

Comment: look at `summary(rs)` and be on the lookout for missing or infinite values of `color` or `quantity`. Probably `color` is not a continuous variable. `plot` looks for continuous variables to make a scatterplot. Are you sure this is what you want? Probably you want `boxplot` or `barplot`.

Comment: @MichaelChirico Tried `boxplot`. It shows `object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`